# Handle & in argument to Windows sendto script

Tags: windows, cmd

I've got a shell:sendto script like this:

```
script.bat:
    python script.py %1
```

so I can right-click a file and get its path passed to `script.py`. However, cmd appears to truncate the path if it contains an `&`. Is there a way to quote `%1` or something to avoid this?

On Windows 7.

Comment: Why a script rather than a shortcut?  IIRC, a shortcut should work just as well, and wouldn't misbehave when the path contains an ampersand.  (That said, putting the `%1` in quote marks would probably work too.)

Comment: Yes a shortcut works, I didn't realise you could do that, thanks. You can convert to an answer if you want the rep :-). I had tried "%1" and that didn't work for me.